# Question on the inequalities of a parabola function

Tags: quadratics

I have a question here from a textbook.

Show that $x^2 +2kx +9 \ge 0$ for all real values of $x$ if $k^2 \le 9$

Here's my proof:

I found values of $k$ to be between $ -3\le k\le3 $

For all real values of $x$, $b^2 -4ac \le 0 \Rightarrow $ no real roots.

I feel there is a  relationship between the value of y and $b^2-4ac$

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the correct statement is $b^2 -4ac \le 0 \Rightarrow$ **no real distinct roots**.

From this condition we obtain

$$4k^2-36\le 0\iff-3\le k\le3$$

Answer (score 1):

Proof:

If the quadratic

$f(x) = x^2+ 2kx +9$ has only complex roots then

$f(x) \ge 0.$

Let $z_1=z$ , $z_2 = \overline z$  be the complex roots.

Then for  real $x$:

$f(x) =(x-z)(x-\overline z)=(x-z)(\overline{x-z})\ge 0,$

since $c\overline c =|c|^2 \ge 0$, where $c \in \mathbb{C}.$

Now follow zam's and gimusi's arguments.

Comment: Thank for the quote :)

Answer (score 0):

$$0\le x^2+2kx+9=(x+k)^2+9-k^2$$

Clearly, $(x+k)^2\ge0$ for  real $x+k$  So, we need $$9-k^2\ge0$$

Comment: I don't understand this. For $(x+k)^2$, can't $x$ and $k$ be complex numbers? Wait I get it now

Answer (score 0):

Your intuition is right. For $k^2=9$ we have the only root $x_1=x_2=-k$ and for $k^2<9$ we have two distinct and conjugate complex roots e.g. for $k=1$ we have $$x^2+2x+9=(x+1)^2+8>0$$